# Layout is not placed correctly? (Still doesn't work)

Tags: java, android, string, android-layout, android-activity

I have been stuck on an issue for 3 hours now, and would really appreciate your advice. I have an android app which I want to be compatible with small screen sizes. So, as suggested on the Android Documentation, and **many** stack overflow pages, I created a new `Android Resource Directory`:

[image: Directories]

In my `layout-small,` I copy and pasted one of the xml layouts of a layout that was overlapping in small screen size. So now, it looks like this:

[image]

By the way, I just copied and pasted the layout `activity_finished_before_timer.xml`. Now, in my manifest, I specified the following. I don't know if this is necessary, but after spending hours online searching for the answer, I added it just in case:

```
<supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
```

After doing **everything** I could find for **hours and hours,** the layout is still overlapping. By overlapping, I mean that my textview is under my button on a small screen. It looks fine on a regular screen though.

**So, now I am lost** I would really appreciate **any** feedback on how to resolve this issue of why the layout is **still** being overlapped. It is very odd, since I have done everything I needed to according to all of the sources I looked at. Please help me in figuring out how to make my layout flexible enough for multiple screen sizes.

Thanks so much for your feedback,

Ruchir

Answer (score 0):

I think the screen you're testing with doesn't have the size defined by android for small screens (small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp), that's why it takes the default layout.

Did you try to put the adjusted layout into a folder named `layout-normal` or even `layout-large`?

Comment: What would a screen size that is 240 x 320 come into?

Comment: And what do you mean by "at least?" Shouldn't it be less than?

Comment: I thought small screen covered everything **less than** 426dp x 320dp

Comment: 320 x 240 px (426 x 320 dp). [At least is correct](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), so everything between 470dp x 320dp to 426dp x 320dp is defined as small. I think there aren't any screens with a size below. You can add your layout into a folder named layout-sw600dp, which means min. width of a device for this layout is 600dp, if less, take the default layout.

Comment: So, what would I do to get it to fit on a screen size: 240x320

Comment: Put your current small layout into the default `layout` folder and every else layout, which just looks good on a bigger size into a proper folder. For example, if your layout does not overlap on a screen with a width of 520dp, then you can put it into a folder `layout-sw500dp`. You need to play a bit around, to find the correct sizes.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense. What is the difference between doing something like `layout-sw500dp` and `layout-normal`

Comment: I have no idea what `layout-sw500dp`

Comment: `layout-normal`: using THIS layout, when the screen size is **between** 640dp x 480dp and 470dp x 320dp. `layout-sw500dp`: using THIS layout, when the screen size is **at least** 500dp x ANY. Always the most specific layout file is chosen, if the screen size does not fit to any of these, the default one in the `layout` folder is picked. Read the part [using new size qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95513/discussion-between-ruchir-baronia-and-dabo).

Comment: For some reason, it is working as I go lower, but not on my actual phone...What should I do? Thanks

Comment: Edit your first post and tell us exactly what you did and what's not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95633/discussion-between-ruchir-baronia-and-dabo).

Comment: Should we just talk in the comments, or would you like to continue this discussion in chat?